# getting the date of monday and friday from next week

Tags: datetime, c#-4.0

I have the following method that I use to get the date for Monday and Friday of next week.

For example, today is 1/6/2017. If I ran it, I would hope to get the following results:

> ```
> monday = 1/9/2017
> friday = 1/13/2017
> ```

The method works fine if I run it earlier in the week, but if I run it later like a friday or saturday, it returns the monday and friday dates 2 weeks from now(not next week).

For example, running it today(Friday the 6th), I get the following results:

> ```
> monday = 1/16/2017
> friday = 1/20/2017
> ```

Here is the method:

```
public static DateTime NextWeekRange(DateTime start, DayOfWeek day)
{
    var add_days = ((int)day - (int)start.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
    return start.AddDays(add_days);
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
var monday = NextWeekRange(DateTime.Today.AddDays(i_today), DayOfWeek.Monday);
var friday = NextWeekRange(DateTime.Today.AddDays(i_today + 4), DayOfWeek.Friday);
```

I'm not quite sure what I got wrong, so another pair of eyes would help!

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `i_today` in your last code block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime MyDate = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime NextMondayDate;
        DateTime NextFridayDate;
        Boolean Test = true;
        while (Test)
        {
            if (MyDate.DayOfWeek.ToString().ToUpper() == "MONDAY")
            {
                NextMondayDate = MyDate;
                NextFridayDate = MyDate.AddDays(4);
                Test = false;
            }

            else if (MyDate.DayOfWeek.ToString().ToUpper() == "FRIDAY")
            {
                NextFridayDate = MyDate;
                NextMondayDate = MyDate.AddDays(3);
                Test = false;
            }
            else
            {
                MyDate = MyDate.AddDays(1);
            } 

        }
```

Comment: The principle is to test your current date: 3 cases occurs:

1- if the current date is "Monday" then automatically the date of Friday is Monday + 4 days. Exp (09/01/2017 == "Monday") 09/01/2017 + 4 days = 13/01/2017 == "Friday")

2- The same Principle if the current date is equal to Friday. In this case the date of monday is the date of Friday + 3 Days.
Exp (13/09/2017 == Friday) 13/09/2017 + 3 days = 16/09/2017 == Monday

3-if the current date does not apply to (1 or2) then add one day to our current date.and we restart the test.